# npm init @eslint/config gives ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a React application created using cra. When I run `npm init @eslint/config`, I get the following error:
[image]

I have tried using `npm cache verify`.
[image]

I also tried using `npm cache clean --force` despite the warnings but the error is the same.

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Heyy! Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @AdarshDubey Unfortunately, I wasn't able to identify the root cause of the problem. As a result, I had to create a new project and perform the initialization process from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused due to missing package [@eslint/create-config](https://github.com/eslint/create-config).

Solution:

1. Install the package with either

```
npm i @eslint/create-config --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn -D add @eslint/create-config
```

2. Execute command `npm init @eslint/config` will work.